# Could you let us see the average reputation of the search results in the free trial mode?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I've made a search on careers to determine whether it could be a good tool for hiring great people, and my search returned me 15 results (I can't see the details as I've not subscribed yet).

What would help me making a decision (about subscribing) would be to know whether those 15 matches are rather in the 10k+ area or in the <100 rep area.

Could you add a feature that would give us a glimpse on that, such as the average rep or maybe a rough idea of the distribution?

Comment: Answering all those `subjective` and `best-practices` questions will finally pay off!